# Swift shift range by 2 or exclude the found character

Tags: swift, swift3

this might be a basic question but I am having a hard time not including the - in the second

```
var title1 = "I will be part of string 1 - I am part of string 2"
let end = title1.range(of: "-", options: .backwards)?.lowerBound
let firstPartRange = title1.startIndex..<end!
var secondPart = title1.substring(with: firstPartRange) // Gives me "I will be part of string 1" which is correct 

title1.substring(from: end!) // however this guy gives me "- I am part of string 2" & I only want to get "I am part of string 2" without the space and dash in front
```

Can I shift the range or change it's lowerBound somehow?. I know I can user separate component by function here but would like to learn how to offset my range

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get the index after end or offset it by 2. Note that you should also make sure it doesn't pass the end index using the method `index(theIndex, offsetBy: n, limitedBy: endIndex)`

```
let title1 = "I will be part of string 1 - I am part of string 2"
if let end = title1.range(of: "-", options: .backwards)?.lowerBound {
    let firstPartRange = title1.startIndex..<end
    let secondPart = title1.substring(with: firstPartRange)  // "I will be part of string 1 "

    title1.substring(from: title1.index(after: end))         // " I am part of string 2"

    // or to offset it by two you should also make sure it doesn't pass the end index 
    title1.substring(from: title1.index(end, offsetBy: 2, limitedBy: title1.endIndex) ?? title1.endIndex)   // "I am part of string 2"
}
```

Comment: You need to append a `trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)` to get OP's desired result.

Comment: or just offsetBy 2

Comment: Sure, let OP decide :-) Of course, trimming removes from *both* ends.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `index(_:offsetBy:)`. This is a method *of the original string*, like this:

```
var title1 = "I will be part of string 1 - I am part of string 2"
let end = title1.range(of: "-", options: .backwards)!.lowerBound
let ix = title1.index(end, offsetBy: 2)
title1.substring(from: ix) // "I am part of string 2"
```

Comment: `let ix = title1(end, offsetBy: 2)` is wrong it should be `let ix = title1.index(end, offsetBy: 2)`

Comment: BTW this would crash if the original string ends in `"-"`

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the contents of string by using **components(separatedBy: String)** method which will return you with array of separated strings then you can remove white spaces from the last element.

```
var title1 = "I will be part of string 1 - I am part of string 2"

print(title1.components(separatedBy: "-").last!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
```

it will give you the desired result

> "I am part of string 2"

Hope it helps!

Comment: OP mentioned he was aware of such solution ;-) Anyway, good to have this made explicit for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the components function and include the spaces in the separator:

```
title1.components(separatedBy:" - ")
```

Answer (score 0):

As @matt suggest, you are looking for `index(_:offsetBy:)`

A little bit different approach using Swift standard library only (no Foundation)

```
let str = "I will be part of string 1 - I am part of string 2"
let parts = str.characters.split(separator: "-").map(String.init)
```

if you would like to trim all extra spaces

```
let partsTrimmed = parts.map {
    $0.characters.split(separator: " ").map(String.init).joined(separator: " ")
}
```